# alert() multiple values in multiple array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object of Customers; and multiple instances of that objects in customers array:

Here's better picture:

```
customers[0].first_name = "anna";
customers[0].last_name = "dan";
customers[0].email = "anna@example.com";
customers[0].credit_card = "222.324.123"
```

There are several of these arrays with different info: customers[1], customers[2] etc..

I need to alert everything out so it looks like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| Customers that have signed up:                    |
|                                                   |
| anna dan    anna@example.com    222.324.123       |
| contents of customer[1]                           |
| contents of customer[2]                           |
| contents of customer[3]                           |
| contents of customer[4]                           |
| and so on ...                                     |
|----------------------------------------------------
```

I don't need to alert the borders that you see, I just drew those to represent how the alert box should be formatted.

Here's what I tried doing which isn't working:

```
for (i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
    if (customer[i].hasSignedUp(query) == true) {
      R_fname[i] = customers[i].f_name;
      R_lname[i] = customers[i].l_name;
      R_email[i] = customers[i].email;
      R_credit[i] = customers[i].credit_card;
    }
  }

  var fin_str;

  for (i = 0; i < R_fname.length; i++) {
    fin_str += (R_fname[i] + " " + R_lname[i] + "    " + R_email[i] + "    " + R_credit[i] + " \n");
  }

  alert("Customer that have signed up " + "\n" + fin_str);
```

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean?  Do you get an error?  Is the output not what you expected?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cgjx1kjx/

Comment: it gives me undfined

Comment: It's because you're not paying close enough attention to your array's object key names.

Comment: Check my answer out, you are setting things to be the ith index in `R_` arrays but the i-1 index might not exist, this has strange effects on you second for loop.  Also you don't define `fin_str` as an empty string and therefore the concatentated string will start with `undefined`

Comment: It's not printing anything

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems, I have fixed them below

```
var R_fname = [],
    R_lname = [],
    R_email = [],
    R_credit = [];
for (i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
    if (customer[i].hasSignedUp(query) == true) {
      R_fname.push(customers[i].f_name);
      R_lname.push(customers[i].l_name);
      R_email.push(customers[i].email);
      R_credit.push(customers[i].credit_card)
    }
  }

  var fin_str = "";

  for (i = 0; i < R_fname.length; i++) {
    fin_str += (R_fname[i] + " " + R_lname[i] + "    " + R_email[i] + "    " + R_credit[i] + " \n");
  }

  alert("Customer that have signed up " + "\n" + fin_str);
```

Basically what I have done is define those `R_` variables as empty arrays.  Used `.push()` so the new element goes at the end and doesn't skip any indexes, and defined `fin_str` as an empty string so string concatenation works properly.

As others have mentioned however, logging should be done with `console.log` which handles lots of different formats including straight up objects / arrays very nicely.

Comment: The use of `alert()` appears to be part of an assignment.

Comment: Strange assignment, but whatever floats his boat :P

Answer (score 1):

Alert isn't a good fit to print out the values of an array.  Console.log would work more effectively.

Comment: I know, assignment forces me to use alert()  ;(

Answer (score 0):

I see you create intermediate arrays R_fname, R_lname, etc, which is unnecessary and may be confusing. You could use customers array directly:

```
var fin_str="";
for (i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
    fin_str += (customers[i].first_name + " " + customers[i].last_name + " " +customers[i].email + " " + customers[i].credit_card + "\n");
}
 alert("Customer that have signed up " + "\n" + fin_str);
```

This approach is verbose and not maintenance-free (any time customers object changes, you will need to adjust this code), but you have full control of the order and formatting.

Comment: You completely removed part of the validation in OP's code.  The `hasSignedUp(query)` bit to be precise.  And those arrays could be used elsewhere....